# c# asp.net displaying image in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I wish to display an image in a gridview.

I have a database with 4 columns - id, author, comment, filename (which holds the img path)

http://postimg.org/image/4loz8t9fb/

I have an image upload method so when the user writes his comment, chooses a photo and clicks submit- his name, the comment and the photo path goes to the database (and the photo itself is uploaded to 'Images' folder in the project folder).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
                   Font-Names = "Arial" Height="375px" Width="498px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" >
                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" SortExpression="Author" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">

                      <ItemTemplate >

                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' height="120px" Width="150px" />

                      </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

here is the c# code-

```
protected void addcomment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = "";
        if (fileupload.PostedFile != null)
        {
             FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
             //Save files to disk
             fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + FileName));

        }




        if (TextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            string name = firstName + " " + lastName;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into comments values(@name,@comment,@filename)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", Server.MapPath("Images/" + FileName));
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "You have to type something buddy!";
        }

    }
```

The gridview datasource is the sql of course.

Here is an image of the database and the website

http://postimg.org/image/4loz8t9fb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont set full path ,

```
 string savepath = "~/Images/" + Filename;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", savepath));
```

just change this line it will work

and even change

```
 fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileName));
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting but what you've written is still saving full path, and as always does not work

Comment: Yes I did, and it still saves the full image path (why is it wrong to use full path?)

Comment: if u use full path, database wont call, because database may be in different computer, so it calls only server folder.

Comment: check this... instead of calling server.mappath in cmd parameter call string

Comment: Thank you very much! apparently your first answer was correct.
you saved me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageUrl ='<%# "Images\\"+Eval("FileName") %>'
```

try this way...

Answer (score 0):

in your design view click on smart tag of your `gridview` and select 'Edit Columns...' then in the opened window create an `ImageField` and in it's properties on right side of window, under 'Data' pane set the property 'DataImageUrlField' to the field that contains your urls that in this case is 'FileName'. it should works.